# M.V. Studio C++ - 2D Arrays NOT working with Files

Tags: c++, arrays, file, multidimensional-array

I am new to C++ (so, please forgive me for my C++ atrocities) and am asking for help once again to the helpful people at stack Overflow. I **have** **to** create a 2D Array program that reads from 2 files, one named after the Months of the year, and the other being a table of integer values.

I have four functions that break off of main in a switch menu. **Function One** should display the whole chart with the months going down the first column.
[Months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A18k9.png) && [Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWYvg.png). So, basically the months are all in the first column[0] and the values line up adjacent to the months (there will be some added flair to the top most row to give a description of what the values are, but I am sure I can figure that part out)

Then the **second function** takes all the values in column [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A18k9.png) & [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWYvg.png) (so not [0] because that's the months).

Then my **third function** takes columns [4] & [5] and adds them up and displays the totals, with the months to left of the values.

My **fourth and final function** will allow a user to input a given month and display the value display in the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A18k9.png) first column after the months.

All of my output is never ending 0's.

Please if you could give me any tips/advice/code examples/anything would be greatly appreciated, and I thank you for taking your time to read this garbage code, so that I can hopefully get better at programming! Here is my code, I have not finished it yet since I keep having loop errors that display 0's when I try to ask the program to display one of the four options.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
// Global Array Size
const int ROWS = 12, COLUM = 9;
int parkChart[ROWS][COLUM];

//Function Prototypes
void displayCodes(const int[][COLUM], int);
int totalRecNonRec(const int[][COLUM], int rows, int total);
int tentRvByMonth(const int[][COLUM], int);
int displayMonth(const int[][COLUM], int, string);

int main()
{
    // Define variables
    const int DISPLAY = 1, REC_NONREC = 2, TENT_RV = 3, PER_MONTH = 4;
    int response, total = 0;
    string month;
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("Months.txt");
    ifstream inputFile2;
    inputFile2.open("Vistors.txt");
    
    cout << "Visitors to National Park" << endl;
    // Do While Loop to display the menu 

    cout << "Enter 1 to display data" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 2 to display total number of recreation and non-recreational visitors" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 3 to display total tent and RV campers by month" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 4 to display the number of recreational visitors for a certain month" << endl;
    cout << "Enter any other number to exit" << endl << "\n";
    cin >> response;
    do
    {
        switch (response)
        {
            case(DISPLAY):
            {
                inputFile;
                inputFile2;
                displayCodes(parkChart, ROWS);
                break;
            }
            case(REC_NONREC):
            {
                totalRecNonRec(parkChart, ROWS, total);
                break;

            }
            case(TENT_RV):
            {
                tentRvByMonth(parkChart, ROWS);
                break;

            }
            case(PER_MONTH):
            {
                displayMonth(parkChart, ROWS, month);
                break;

            }
            default:
            {

                // Closes the file and exits
                inputFile.close();
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    } while (response == 1 || response == 2 || response == 3|| response == 4);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// Four Functions
// Display Function
void displayCodes(const int parkChart[][COLUM], int ROWS)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLUM; col++)
        {
            cout << parkChart[row][col] << "\t ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
}
// Totals/Display Rec. & Non Rec. Visitors to the park + adds all months for visitors (must equal 3,350,493)
int totalRecNonRec(const int parkChart[][COLUM], int rows, int total)
{
    // for loop that adds all the elements in [0-11,1]&&[0-11,2]
    for (int col = 0; col < 1; col++)
    {
        total = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
            total += col;
        cout << "The total number of recreational and non-recreational visitors: " << total << endl;
    }
    return total;
}
// Totals/Display Number of Tent & RV Campers by month (needs to add rv + tent) and show all months
int tentRvByMonth(const int parkChart[][COLUM], int rows)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (int col = 4; col < 5; col++)
        {
            total += parkChart[row][col];
            cout << parkChart[row][col] << " " << (col + 1) << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int displayMonth(const int parkChart[][COLUM], int rows, string month)
{
    // Prompt the user to enter a month/Display the number of Rec. Visitors for that month + Failsafe of non-months
    // Need a for loop to search for the user given month, and then display the [month, 1]
    cout << "Enter the month you want the number of recreational visitors\n";
    getline(cin, month);
    // search in first column of array
    
    cout << "For the month of " << month << " there were " << " recreational visitors" << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To me, it looks like your columns of the inner arrays have specific meanings. In this case, the inner array should be a `struct` or `class` instead. The added value is that you can drop the 2d arrays. (Not that I scare 2d arrays but they are not easy to manage and may consume your attention which might be invested better to other aspects of your program.)

Comment: Understandable and I appreciate the tips, but unfortunately it's required that I use a 2D Array for this program.

Comment: I somehow expected that. ;-) What's your actual question? If you're looking for code review then [Stack Exchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be the better place to post.

Comment: I am aware of the errors, and NO I cannot use Stack Exchange Code Review since the code has to be working with no bugs. I am posting it here for any advice or tips on direction I should take. It was requested and required that I use a 2D array, so why does it matter where it "came from" or the "design" since I stated all relevant information in the text block above. I am student struggling during these COVID times and it was required by my mentor that I use 2D Arrays. I am just asking for advice or tips on what I can do to make this work ! Code examples appreciated but not required. :-)